# how can i Create 2 separate navigators with different route configs in react-navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

i have two roles in my app and i want to create seprate route configs for each of them like this:

```
const ADMIN_ROUTES = {
  home: { screen: HomeNavigator },
  listings: { screen: ListingsNavigator }, // admin only screen/tab
  account: { screen: AccountNavigator }
};

const REGULAR_ROUTES = {
  home: { screen: HomeNavigator },
  buildingList: { screen: buildingListNavigator }
};
```

could you help me how i can do it?

Thanks in advance